# Overscan creates unwanted border in some apps

Tags: android, adb

I ran

```
Process process Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wm overscan 0,80,0,0");
```

But in some apps like whatsapp or my launcher it creates an additional border that I don't want. Is there anything I can do against it? In the attaches screenshot it's black.

[image]

Also, it would be great if I found a way to change the overscan color, I don't really want to use the status bar color but a black instead.

Comment: did you get this running without root? I tried it after granting my app `WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission but still get `Can't find service: window` error...